# Multiple Regular Expression Search and Replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Is there a way in Sublime Text to execute multiple regular expression search and replace *queries* at once.

For example I want to (in the order listed)

1. Find strings matching *regex1* and replace them with *regex1replacement*
2. Find strings matching *regex2* and replace them with *regex2replacement*
3. Find strings matching *regex3* and replace them with *regex3replacement*
4. Find strings matching *regexN* and replace them with *regexNreplacement*

At once.

The string: "blah regex1, bloo regex2, bleep regex3"
Would become : "blah regex1replacement, bloo regex2replacement, bleep regex3replacement"

This is something that can be easily scripted, but I currently don't have that freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: Oh sorry I missed that you want this in sublime text. Sorry!

```
sed 's/regex1/regex1replacement/g;s/regex2/regex2replacement/g;s/regex3/regex3replacement/g;'
```

For a cleaner script, I think this will work, but I haven't tested:

```
sed "s/regex1/regex1replacement/g; \
     s/regex2/regex2replacement/g; \
     s/regex3/regex3replacement/g;"
```